# pre selecting items in select box rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

UPDATE

```
@selected
attributes: 
group_id: "29"
attributes_cache: {}
@data
attributes: 
created_at: 2010-06-19 10:16:13
term_id: "1"
updated_at: 2010-06-19 10:16:13
id: "29"
course_id: "1"
```

Hi,

I am trying to pre-select items within a select_tag

```
 <%= select_tag "contact[group_ids][]",
       options_for_select(
         @data.map{ |d| [" Term #{d.term.number} #{d.term.start_date} #{d.course.course_type} #{d.course.course_name}"] },
         @selected.map{ |j| j.id }
       ),
       :multiple => true
%>
```

The @data object is all the items in the list and @selected contains the id's of the ones that should be selected.

Any ideas why they are not being selected ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using - options_from_collection_for_select()

http://shiningthrough.co.uk/Select-helper-methods-in-Ruby-on-Rails

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's just

```
<%= select_tag "contact[group_ids][]",
       options_for_select(
         @data.map{ |d| [" Term #{d.term.number} #{d.term.start_date} #{d.course.course_type} #{d.course.course_name}"] },
         @selected
       ),
       :multiple => true
%>
```

because [`railsapi.com`](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#M002253) says:

> "`selected` may also be an array of
>   values to be selected when using a
>   multiple select"

**Edit**

I thought `@selected` was an array of IDs, but it isn't. So the way you first write your code (with `@selected.map{ |j| j.id }`) should work.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried that after looking at the api but had no luck. I have added what my objects look like, are they ok ?

Comment: I thought `@selected` was an array of IDs... But `@selected.map{ |j| j.id }` should work then :/